# OpenCart Customer Password Encryption

Tags: ios, encryption, md5, opencart

In my iOS app I am trying to allow users to login to the store with their current user info that is already in the OpenCart system. If I understand correctly, the passwords are encrypted using MD5. When I encrypt the password from the app it doesn't match what is stored in the database. Any suggestions on why this may be? And any suggestions on how to solve it? This is the first time I have ever done anything of this sort.

Comment: Both the question and answer (though correct) are missing the OpenCart version since the password encryption has changed from one version to another significantly (do not remember whether from 1.4.X to 1.5.0 or between some 1.5.X versions). So check the user model of your OpenCart installation and make the password encryption identical in your iOS app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to user model of OpenCart, password encryption is a bit more complex, than just MD5:

```
public function addUser($data) {
    $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "user` SET username = '" . $this->db->escape($data['username']) . "', salt = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)) . "', password = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($data['password'])))) . "', firstname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['firstname']) . "', lastname = '" . $this->db->escape($data['lastname']) . "', email = '" . $this->db->escape($data['email']) . "', user_group_id = '" . (int)$data['user_group_id'] . "', status = '" . (int)$data['status'] . "', date_added = NOW()");
}
```

So first you generate salt like this:

```
$salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9);
```

Then you encrypt password:

```
$password = sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($data['password'])));
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer, as it is what led me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Finally! Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1):

I made a slight modification to the code above.

```
$password = sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($password)))
```

Also, I am not generating a new user in this case, I am just encrypting the password and then comparing it to the db. As far as that goes I do have a security question. Is is better to encrypt on the phone and then push it, or is it better to push the normal text and then encrypt with a service? The latter is what I am currently doing.

Comment: Sorry to revive an old thread but an answer could be good here. It is always better to encrypt on the phone rather than sending as normal text and let the server encrypt it, simply because if someone intercepts the comunication between the phone and the server he will have full access to the password (and other important information), while when it is encrypted he can't (in theory of course) get the password, and the server would understand it without spending resources encrypting it...

So it's a win-win :)